# Generate new matrix from A containing the average value of A rows for each column if B[i, j] == 1 where B is an adjacency matrix

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, mean, adjacency-matrix

How can we get a new matrix containing the average value of A row for each column if B[i,j] == 1 ?

Suppose we have a matrix A(3,4) and a matrix B(3,3)

```
A =  [1      2     3      4
      15     20    7      10 
      0      5     18     12]
```

And an adjacency matrix

```
 B = [1    0     1   
      0    0     1    
      1    1     1 ]
```

Expected output matrix C which takes the average value of the connected pixels in B :

for example `[(1+0)/2  (2+5)/2  (3+18)/2  (4+12)/2]` so we get `[0.5 , 3.5 10.5 8]` in the first row.

```
           C =[0.5     3.5   10.5   8
               0        5     18   12
               5.33    9      9.33   8.66]
```

To find the neighborhood of each i, I implemented the following code :

```
for i in range(A.shape[0]):
    for j in range(A.shape[0]):
        if (B[i,j] == 1):
            print(j)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can form the sums you need by matrix multiplying:

```
>>> A = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4], [15, 20, 7, 10], [0, 5, 18, 12]])
>>> B = np.array([[1, 0, 1], [0, 0, 1], [1, 1, 1]])

>>> summed_groups = B@A
>>> summed_groups
array([[ 1,  7, 21, 16],
       [ 0,  5, 18, 12],
       [16, 27, 28, 26]])
```

To get the means normalize by the number of terms per group:

```
>>> group_sizes = B.sum(axis=1,keepdims=True)
>>> group_sizes
array([[2],
       [1],
       [3]])

>>> summed_groups / group_sizes
array([[ 0.5       ,  3.5       , 10.5       ,  8.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  5.        , 18.        , 12.        ],
       [ 5.33333333,  9.        ,  9.33333333,  8.66666667]])
```

Side note: you could also get the group sizes by matrix multiplication:

```
>>> group_sizes_alt = B@np.ones((len(A),1))
>>> group_sizes_alt
array([[2.],
       [1.],
       [3.]])
```

Comment: A good thing of this solution compared to mine is that it uses efficient matrix operations rather than explicit iterating over rows, which can be important if you need to do this over big datasets. The downside is that it is less transparent and therefore harder to review.

Answer (score 0):

It is convenient to use boolean indexing. For example,

```
>>> A[[True, False, True], :]

array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 0,  5, 18, 12]])
```

this selects rows 0 and 2 of the `A` matrix. You can loop over the columns of `B` and construct the `C` matrix:

```
A = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4], [15, 20, 7, 10], [0, 5, 18, 12]])
B = np.array([[1, 0, 1], [0, 0, 1], [1, 1, 1]]).astype(bool)
C = np.array([A[B[:, i], :].mean(axis=0) for i in range(A.shape[0])])
print(np.around(C, 2))
```

Result:

```
[[ 0.5   3.5  10.5   8.  ]
 [ 0.    5.   18.   12.  ]
 [ 5.33  9.    9.33  8.67]]
```